# Using PHP and MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and namly PROJECT, PROGRESS AND PAYMENT .

I have one table name as PROJECT in that I have following columns.

```
ID | TITLE| ADDEDBY
718  CIVIL  XYZ
```

I have one table name as PROGRESS in that I have following  columns.

```
PARENTPROJECT ID | PROGRESS_PERCENTAGE|ADDEDBY
718                      65              XYZ
718                      45              XYZ
```

I have one table name as PAYMENT in that i have following  collumn

```
PARENTPROJECT ID |RELEASE _AMT|ADDEDBY
718                 785632      XYZ
718                 582568      XYZ
```

There is multiple entry of project id in the PROGRESS AND PAYMENT TABLES, I WANT TO FETCH THE PROJECT ID , SUM OF RELEASE AMT FROM PAYMENT TABLE AGAINST THAT PROJECT ID AND MAXIMUM PROGRESS PERCENTAGE FROM PROGRESS TABLE AGAINST THAT PROJECT ID.

Now, what I tried is like this:-

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       a.P_TITLE, 
       a.P_TYPE, 
       a.ZONE, 
       a.CIRCLE, 
       a.P_LOCATION, 
       a.AAES_AMT, 
       a.CONTRACTORNAME, 
       a.P_STARTDATE, 
       a.P_ENDDATE, 
       a.A_STARTDATE, 
       a.A_ENDDATE, 
       a.P_ESTIMATECOST, 
       a.TENDERCOST, 
       a.P_STATUS, 
       MAX(b.PROGRESS_PERCENTAGE)         AS progress_percentage, 
       ( SUM(c.RELEASE_AMT) )             AS r_amt, 
       ( ( R_AMT / a.TENDERCOST ) * 100 ) AS fin 
FROM   project a 
       INNER JOIN progress b 
               ON a.ID = b.PARENTPROJECTID 
       INNER JOIN paymnet c 
               ON a.ID = c.PARENTPROJECTID 
WHERE  a.ADDEDBY = 'XYZ' 
GROUP  BY a.ID
```

But I am not getting the result..

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT US

Comment: `INNER JOIN paymnet c` you misspelled `payment`

Comment: i knew it but still is not giving me the required result

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo the mysqli_error($link) after running the query to see what the problem is *Link being whatever your mysql connection variable is*